Can I use useCallback or useMemo in a server component?
I am building a Next.js (14, App Router) application and although it is not really needed the company would like me to use useCallback in server components for consistency across all components. I came across a strange error where it seemed to not recognize useCallback and I tracked it down to having an await followed by useCallback.
Here is a minimal example:
import { FC, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';

export const Test: FC = async () => {
  const getAsyncStuff = async () => 'async stuff';

  // If I await this function
  await getAsyncStuff();

  // This line causes Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useCallback')
  const getStuff = useCallback(() => 'stuff', []);

  // This line causes Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
  const stuff = useMemo(() => 'stuff', []);

  return null;
};

I couldn't find any definitive documentation so my question is: Are these hooks supported in server components? And if so, how do I avoid this problem?

useCallback and useMemo are for client components. They are not used in server components. server components don't rerender so they don't need hooks. You can either remove those hooks or you can convert your component into a client component by adding "use client" at the top of your component.
'use client'; // Client Component

import { FC, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';

export const Test: FC = () => {
  const getStuff = useCallback(() => 'stuff', []);
  const stuff = useMemo(() => 'stuff', []);

  return null;
};

